# Android - Disable the Onclick

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-view, android-image

I am new to android. I get the code from internet which is below

```
View.OnClickListener loadImage = new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {

            loadImage(imageLocation);

            }
     };

     void loadImage(String image_location){

          URL imageURL = null;

          try {
              imageURL = new URL(image_location);
            } 

          catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }

          try {
              HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection)imageURL.openConnection();
              connection.setDoInput(true);
              connection.connect();
              InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

              bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);//Convert to bitmap
              Bitmap drawableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
              drawView.setCanvasBitmap(drawableBitmap);

          }
          catch (IOException e) {

               e.printStackTrace();
          }
     }
```

This method will load the image from URL when the button is clicked. It is worked but I need to load the image from URL when activity is launch.

How should I modify the code to remove the onClick ? Kindly look for helps. Thanks =)

Comment: Have you heard the life cycle of `Activity` ? first check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I think you should read some documentation on http://developer.android.com before trying to load images from URL...

Comment: Where is this code in your application, Is it inside an activity or some where else ?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.abc);
    loadImage(imageLocation);

}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Call loadImage() method from your activity's oncreate() method.

By this way it will be called when activity is launched...

Comment: It not worked. I had tried.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the method `loadImage(imageLocation);` in onCreate() of your application and remove onClick() method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in the onCreate() methord ,you can do this code:

```
loadImage.performClick();
```